# Regex to add an extension to a directory full of files

Tags: regex

I am new to regular expressions.

I have many irregularly numbered ascii files with no extension: g000554, g000556, g000558, g000561, g000563 ... g001979 etc

I would like to type a regex at the terminal (or in a short script) to add a .dat to all of these files.

So I would like to change them to become: g000554.dat, g000556.dat, g000558.dat, g000561.dat, g000563.dat ... g001979.dat etc

p.s. Sorry I should have provided more info: by terminal I meant a mac terminal and I cannot use the 'rename' command.

Comment: terminal? which terminal?

Comment: It depends which programming language you're using also.

Comment: You don't really need a regex beyond `*`,  and you're looking for `mmv`.

Comment: Match "`/$/`" and replace with ".dat". Also you don't really need a regex...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using a linux system. So i provide a bash solution. It works only if your files starts with `g` and there is no other files in that directory except the files you want to rename.

```
for i in g*; do mv "$i" "$i.dat"; done
```

The below would add `.dat` extension to all the files present in the current directory,

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" "$i.dat"; done
```

Comment: How do I bulk change filenames. For example I have Suns000554.dat, Suns000556.dat, Suns000558.dat ...etc and I want to change them to be s000554.dat, s000556.dat, s000558.dat